# Great name! It's puzzling indeed to finally see how a question can be made sense of after reading the site name

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Of course, I did not notice the site name because I was coming from the hot network question sidebar.

I read [Mysterious message from the NoSlaves™ Calculator Co](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/mysterious-message-from-the-noslaves%e2%84%a2-calculator-co) to the end - wasting a little time.

I did check the posting date for being first of april, in mid-reading though.

Can that case somehow be prevented?

Comment: I barely understand what you're saying. Could you be more clear please? Looks like you unintentionally read a puzzle, thought it was April Fool and you're disappointed. Did I misinterpreted your message?

Comment: That's right, except that I I only check whether it was April fool related when it got a suspicion that it may be a joke.

Comment: I am trying to make sense of this: I think, a user who comes here via HotNetworkQuestions reads the question, thinking that it is a **request for help** (like most other SE forums) & when he wants to help, he reads the whole question, which does not look like a request for help, or it even contains **aliens, message bottles, ciphers, rebuses , etc**. Now the user (Volker Siegel is an example) has wasted his time, & thinks that this must be some April Fool Joke. So he wants to know if there is a way to prevent this. I feel this must go to Meta or SE, for filtering HNQ based on user preference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about filtering HNQ based on user preference.

Comment: @Prem I do not think it's about filteriing the HNQ - To me, that sounds like a bad idea. I noticed now tha part of the issue depends on the beta state of the site. Beta sites do not indicate the cuestion context in the design, which can be very strong, and could solve most of the issue when leaving beta. The game sites with a typical design solve much of the problem.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel , I am happy that my interpretation of your question was 90% correct, so the question was moved to meta, it was answered as per my interpretation , and then you got your answer. Regarding the 10% which was partially off target, your original meaning (which is not at all clear in your question) is you do not want **automatic filtering in HNQ**, you only want some indication there that this is about Puzzles. HNQ list is too small for such elaborateness; the only other solution is to visit the question, and then avoid that type henceforth, which becomes **manual filtering in HNQ**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You learned something about the hot list today - many titles only make sense in the context of their site. In future, you can hover over the link before you click it. If the link is on worldbuilding or puzzling, you can expect that the question pertains to an alternate reality and decide whether you want to click the link or not, and if you do click it you'll arrive in the right frame of mind.

The only prevention would be to order all members of this site to adjust their titles so that anyone seeing them on the hotlist knows somehow that the question is a puzzle. That would be very confining for **no benefit** - anyone seeing them on the hotlist can know they are a puzzle by observing they were posted at puzzling.se.

A small number of users had no idea puzzling.se exists, and the hot list actually exists for just this reason - to expose all of us to other sites we might not know about. A cognitive scientist might answer that the small "jar" you experienced as you came to learn that p.se exists and what it is all about is just the ticket for locking that material into your brain. That even further lowers the incentive to force p.se users to choose suboptimal titles just to minimize dissonance for hot list users.

Comment: +1 and accepting blindly for the last paragraph, before reading in whole.

Comment: That just locked it into mine.